# How to create a python api?

Tags: python-2.7, api, tensorflow, classification, ubuntu-16.04

I am a computer vision student and I am faced with a task that goes beyond by field of expertise. I was given a task to create an api that takes an image url as input and it gives prediction of which type of food is in the image.
I used tensorflow with inception to classify my data. I have now a python script that takes a url and basically it downloads the image, sends it to the classifier and I get predictions on a terminal window on ubuntu.
Now, for the classification, as I said, I used tensorflow with inception, I have now in my script folder a graph file (graph.pb), this file contains the network that does classification (weights), it is more than 80Mb in size.
So all I can do so far is use my script in a terminal and give it an image url and it gives me predictions. I want to turn this into an api so that someone can use it to predict which type of food an image contains. I don't know how to code and API but I can learn. I just want the easiest way to code this in a short amount of time, ideally I would use python to code it, if not then please show me other options that are relatively easy.

So all in all, I want to code an api using python that takes an image url and predicts which type of food that image contains using the weights in the graph.pb file.

Any guidelines are greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need HTTP API. This means that a user will have to make an HTTP request (maybe from a browser) and specify input data in the request parameters, then he will get a response with output data.

To create HTTP API you will need an HTTP server. One of ways of creating one is Flask microframework ([Flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/)).

As you can see in the tutorial, you are creating the HTTP server's functionality by defining special functions handling different *routes*. Simply put, a *route* is a particular type of queries (so queries of this type are handled in this function, of that type - in that one).

I can imagine the code of your HTTP server like this: there is a route handler function doing the very thing. It gathers input data from the request, then uses already implemented functionality of yours (by invoking a function or executing some command, it depends on how exactly your program works), gets its output and returns it as a response on the request.

When finished the HTTP server, you will need to deploy it (along with the recogniser part) on a publicly accessible (I mean everybody can make requests to it) always-on server (VDS will do). Your API will be accessible by the server API or by a domain name if you make one.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it kinda gave me some hints. I found something very interesting  here : https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_inception. Now I believe this is a way to create an API that is supported by tensorflow. Can you please do a quick read of what's in it and tell me whether the end result which they called it "service in Kubernetes" is an API?

Comment: Docker? Not familiar with it, unfortunately. Can't tell.

Comment: I managed to do the job by using MLDB (Machine Learning Database) which is a framework that embeds RESTful calls inside functions.